# Submit Button not triggering javascript functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, next.js, axios

I have a form and functions don't work on those buttons. I am using Axios to do the post request. Is it something related to children layouts? Naming the files? It's the fact of my children layout dont have body or main tags?

main layout

```
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import Head from 'next/head';
import "./globals.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Company Dashboard",
  description: "",
};

export default function DashboardLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="mainContent">
      <Head>
        <title>{metadata.title}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={metadata.description} />
      </Head>
      <header>
        {/* Header content goes here */}
      </header>
      <body>


      <div className="leftMenu">     
        <nav>
                <a href="/"><button>Home</button></a>

                <a href="/admins"><button>Admins</button></a>

                <a href="/employees"><button>Employees</button></a>

                <a href="/clients"><button>Clients</button></a>

                <a href="/cars"><button>Cars</button></a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div className="leftContent"></div>
      <div className="middleContent">{children}</div>
      <div className="rightContent"></div>
      
        
      </body>
    </div>
  );
}
```

code in question

```
'use client'
import React  from "react";
import axios from 'axios';



export default function employees(){

 
  const formDataClass = {name:'',surname:'',email:''}

  async function login() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("URL",formDataClass);
      alert(formDataClass.name);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }


    return(
     
        <div className="content">
        <div><h1>Seja Bem Vindo ao Sistema de Gestão V1.0</h1></div>
        <div className="formulary">
          <div><h3>Formulário de Empregados</h3></div>
          <div>
            <form>
                <input onChange={(e)=>formDataClass.name=e.target.value} placeholder="Insert Your Name"></input>
                <input onChange={(e)=>formDataClass.surname=e.target.value} placeholder="Insert Your Surname"></input>
                <input onChange={(e)=>formDataClass.email=e.target.value} placeholder="Insert your Email"></input>
                <div className="formButtons">
                  <button type="button">Save</button>
                  <button type="button" onClick={login()}>Submit</button>
                  
                </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

        
      </div>
    );
}
```

I did try everything and expect the buttons to trigger the axios post

Comment: Is this just a typo?  I think instead of `onClick={login()}` you meant: `onClick={login}`    (login **is** the function -- it doesn't **return** a function, right?)

Comment: tried this ones but doenst work

Comment: `formDataClass` should be state which you update from your inputs.

Comment: the problem is because my button its not triggering any function, even if i use hooks.. cant i use just a class to make send a form, because i will not be rendering anything

Comment: @user16726047, then **please remove the typo** from the code in your question.  It's hugely distracting.  (`onClick={login()}` is a typo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of below?

```
<button type="button" onClick={login}>Submit</button>
<button type="button" onClick={() => login()}>Submit</button>
```

UPDATE:

After checking your github, noticed that you need below change.

1. Fix Uncaught Error: invariant expected app router to be mounted by editing layout.js (layout needs to have html tag and body tag).
2. you should use useState for handling form value in employees/page.js.

layout.js

```
"use client";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import Head from "next/head";
import "./globals.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

const metadata = {
  title: "Company Dashboard",
  description: "",
};

export default function DashboardLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <Head>
        <title>{metadata.title}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={metadata.description} />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <div className="mainContent">
          <div className="leftMenu">
            <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
              <h4>
                Sistem de Gestão v1.0
                <img
                  className="logo"
                  src="https://www.getautismactive.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Test-Logo-Circle-black-transparent.png"
                  width={"43px"}
                />
              </h4>
            </div>
            <nav>
              <a href="/">
                <button>Home</button>
              </a>

              <a href="/admins">
                <button>Admins</button>
              </a>

              <a href="/employees">
                <button>Employees</button>
              </a>

              <a href="/clients">
                <button>Clients</button>
              </a>
              <a href="/cars">
                <button>Cars</button>
              </a>
            </nav>
          </div>
          <div className="leftContent"></div>
          <div className="middleContent">{children}</div>
          <div className="rightContent"></div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

global.css (only change below line but should fix depends on your need)

```
.logo{
  width: 43px
}
```

After applying above changes, you will see form submission is working.
but you should still can't edit the form because you didn't use useState. you need to fix it.

Comment: yes, i already tried but is not working

Comment: It's weird, try to use onSubmit?
<form onSubmit={(event) => {
event.preventDefault();
login();
}}>
Also change the button type to submit.
                  <button type="submit">Submit</button>

Comment: still not working

Comment: It will be better if you could create codepen or something.

Comment: can this be on github ? 
https://github.com/fsDevLegacyCode/company-dashboard

Comment: Your main issue doesn't exist in form, main issue is "invariant expected app router to be mounted" on your console, that is caused by layout.js, layout.js needs to include html and body tag according to Next.js documentation.
Anyway updated the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257111/discussion-between-plsdev89-and-user16726047).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using React you should be using state to manage your form data.

Your button should be `onClick={login}` because `onClick={login()}` assigns the value of the result of calling `login` to your event handler rather than a reference to the function itself.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  // Set your state
  const [ form, setForm ] = useState({name:'', surname:'', email:''});

  // When the button is clicked do your axios
  // process (but here I'm just logging the form data)
  function login() {
    console.log(form);
  }

  // When an input value is changed grab its name and value
  // and update the form state object
  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setForm(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
  }

  // Make sure you give your inputs names, assign the
  // handleClick function to the onClick handler, and
  // make your inputs controllable by assigning their
  // values to their value contained in state
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        name="name"
        value={form.name}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Insert Your Name"
      />
      <input
        name="surname"
        value={form.surname}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Insert Your Surname"
      />
      <input
        name="email"
        value={form.value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Insert your Email"
      />
      <div className="formButtons">
        <button type="button" onClick={login}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heyy, I think I know how to solve this issue

1st you can add one onSubmit event to the form like given below

ex.

```
<form onSubmit={login}>
  <input/>
</form>
```

as you enter the onSubmit event will occur and the login function will be called

2nd the button inside the form should have type of submit, so when you click on to it, the submit event occur, follow the below step

```
<form onSubmit={login}>
 <input/>
 <button type='**submit**'>submit</button>
</form>
```

hope it works and if doesn't we will make it work.